# Lagom. Throttling for external service

Tags: scala, lagom, akka-typed

I am playing with Lagom, it looks nice, but I completely lost with one issue.

Lets say I have dependency on external HTTP service, it allow only 10 requests/sec, in other case can even ban:) 
I googled, but didn't found any working example. I can wrap service in untyped actor and add rate limiter to it, but I don't understand how to implement it on top of Akka Typed or Lagom service.

Maybe someone solved such task already? Thanks!

Comment: I've opened [an issue](https://github.com/lagom/lagom/issues/1110#issuecomment-345558013) to hopefully address this in the future.

Answer (score 4):

You want a [token bucket](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Token_bucket). Akka-Streams has this built in with [Flow.throttle](https://doc.akka.io/api/akka/current/akka/stream/scaladsl/Flow.html#throttle(elements:Int,per:scala.concurrent.duration.FiniteDuration,maximumBurst:Int,mode:akka.stream.ThrottleMode):FlowOps.this.Repr[Out]) but it sounds like you're using raw akka so can't use that. There exists a [token bucket implementation in Akka](https://doc.akka.io/api/akka/current/akka/util/NanoTimeTokenBucket.html) but unfortunately it doesn't give any guidance on usage, and I've not used it myself.

For my own use-cases (not Akka but using Scala Futures) I wrote my own token bucket. It allows me to refer the triggering of a Future based on the limit specified. It's coded against monix scheduler but that's very similar to the Akka schedule for this purpose:

```
import java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentLinkedQueue

import monix.execution.Scheduler.Implicits.global
import monix.execution.atomic.AtomicInt

import scala.concurrent.{Future, Promise}
import scala.concurrent.duration._

case class RateLimiter(duration: FiniteDuration, maxInvocations: Int) {

  @volatile var permits: Int = maxInvocations
  val queue = new ConcurrentLinkedQueue[() => Any]()

  global.scheduleAtFixedRate(duration, duration) {
    this synchronized {
      permits = maxInvocations

      while (!queue.isEmpty && permits > 0) {
        Option(queue.poll()).foreach { fun =>
          permits -= 1
          fun.apply()
        }
      }
    }
  }

  def apply[T](f: => Future[T]): Future[T] =
    this synchronized {
      if (permits > 0) {
        permits -= 1
        f
      } else {
        val res = Promise[T]()
        queue.add(() => { res.completeWith(f) })
        res.future
      }
    }
}
```

Usage is

```
val limiter = RateLimiter(1.second, 10)

limiter {
  someWebService.asyncCall()
}
```

Comment: Thanks, Grogs. It is awesome, but I thought it should be some standard solution in Lagom for such basic task. Just curious, because I didn't googled anything

Comment: Thanks, Grogs, this was a great template to understand how this can be done in multiple scaling nodes.  https://github.com/lagom-extensions/throttler/tree/master/src/main/scala/com/lightbend/lagom/throttler